# How can I add a foreign key from a table in another database connection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys

I have set up a ASP.net MVC application which uses the default forms authentication. It uses the ASPNETDB.mdf like shown here:
[image]

I then set up another database connection which is similar to the NerdDinner.mdf file above.

I have a post that belongs to a user. It has a UserId value which needs to be a foreign key to the information in ASPNETDB.mdf. When I go to add a foreign key, I can only see information with regards to the table I made. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it were possible (which is isn't), this would be a bad idea - chaining databases in this manner would only cause problems down the line.

- If one database is down, so is the other.
- If the network between database servers (assuming different servers), both are down.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx):

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint can reference columns in **tables in the same database** or within the **same table**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Ah.. thanks. So what are you supposed to do then? I am new to ASP.net if you can't tell!

Comment: @GreenRails - Why do you need different databases? If you do, you can setup a job that will check for "bad" values and report on them.

Comment: No I don't need different ones. I was just following the tutorial with my own stuff. Can I add my tables into the ASPNETDB.mdf?